# How to remove items from a java list - by a set of positions?

Tags: java, list, set

Given a set of positions, `Set<Integer> positionsToRemove`, I'd like to remove all items from a list, `List<?> list`, that their position correspond to the values in the set.

```
public static void remove(List<?> list, Set<Integer> positionsToRemove) {
  // ?
}
```

Notes:

- The list may be long.
- The set may be long.
- Be careful not to fall for IndexOutOfBounds or ConcurrentModificationException.
- You can assume that the list and set do not hold nulls.

Comment: Do your really want to modify your original list, or is returning a new list acceptable?

Comment: @LukasEder - modify the original list.

Comment: If you expect the resulting list to be short, constructing a new list may be faster, depending on the complexity of the `remove()` operation in your original list.

Answer (score 4):

You must ensure to remove items **in reverse**, as otherwise the indices will become invalid.

You can do this very easily with a `List`:

```
public static void remove(List<?> list, Set<Integer> positionsToRemove) {
    final ListIterator<?> iter = list.listIterator(list.size());
    while (iter.hasPrevious()) {
        iter.previous();
        if (positionsToRemove.contains(iter.nextIndex())) {
            iter.remove();
        }
    }
}
```

This takes advantage of the ability if `ListIterator` to provide the current index and also it's ability to iterate in reverse.

It also does not rely on a "marker value" so `null` is allowed in the input `List`.

Obviously you could do this much more simply with an "old style" indexed loop:

```
public static void remove(List<?> list, Set<Integer> positionsToRemove) {
    for (int i = list.size() - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
        if (positionsToRemove.contains(i)) {
            list.remove(i);
        }
    }
}
```

But it should be noted that if the `List` lacks `RandomAccess` this will be `O(n^2)`, whereas the `ListIterator` based solution would be `O(n)` for a `List` that has `O(1)` `remove`.

It may be quicker to return a `new List`, depending on how may elements you are removing and also the type of the `List` - for an `ArrayList` the `remove` operation is quite expensive:

```
public static <T> List<T> remove(List<T> list, Set<Integer> positionsToRemove) {
    return IntStream.range(0, list.size())
            .filter(i -> !positionsToRemove.contains(i))
            .mapToObj(list::get)
            .collect(toList());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void remove(List<?> list, Set<Integer> positionsToRemove) {
    for (Integer position : positionsToRemove) {
        list.set((int)position, null);
    }
    for (Iterator<?> iterator = list.iterator(); iterator.hasNext(); ) {
        Object o =  iterator.next();
        if (o == null) iterator.remove();
    }
}
```

Comment: This will remove other `null` values.

Comment: @BoristheSpider -  See the notes in the question. Nulls aren't allowed.

Comment: You could also use `Object marker = new Object();` and use that as a marker for removal, if `nulls` were allowed

Comment: This (my) solution is problematic because it assumes that the access to a list item is immediate, which is NOT true if it's a LinkedList.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void remove(List<?> list, Set<Integer> positionsToRemove) {
    int i = 0;
    for (Iterator<?> iterator = list.iterator(); iterator.hasNext(); ++i) {
        iterator.next();
        if (positionsToRemove.contains(i)) iterator.remove();
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution looks simpler than all the others.

Comment: Crap! Didn't notice It was an answer by me.